# $\rho:P \to M$ a projective cover for $M$ semi-perfect module. Prove $M$ is indecomposable if and only if $P$ is indecomposable.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, homological-algebra, projective-module

> Let $M \neq \lbrace 0 \rbrace$ be a semi-perfect module and $\rho:P \to M$ a projective cover for $M$. I want to prove that $M$ is indecomposable if and only if $P$ is indecomposable.

All right, we understood by  a **projective** cover of $M$ if there is an epimorphism  $\rho:P \to M$ with $P$ projective and $\ker( \rho )$ is **superfluous** on $M$, $\ker(\rho) << P$, that means that for every submodule $L \leq M$ such $M=\ker(\rho)+L$, then $L=M$, i.e, $\ker(\rho)$ is so small..superfluous.

And we understood by $M$ a **semi-perfect** module if every quotient of $M$ has a projective cover. Also, we say that $M$ is **indecomposable** if the only diret summands of $M$ are $M$ itself and $\lbrace 0 \rbrace $.

So far I have worked just in only one implication. Let's suppose $M$ is semi-perfect and indecomposable, as there are only two quotients we can take in $M$, these are $\frac{M}{\lbrace 0 \rbrace}=M$ and $\frac{M}{M}=\lbrace 0 \rbrace$ and by hypotheses of $M$ being semi-perfect we have the existence of two projective covers, $\rho_{1}:P_{1} \to M$ and $\rho_{2}:P_{2} \to \lbrace 0 \rbrace$, but I dont know how to relate this two projective cover in order to prove that $P$ in th original projective cover  $\rho:P \to M$ of $M$ its indecomposable.

Comment: An indecomposable module can have *many* submodules. It hasn't *direct summands*, which is a very different thing than being simple.

Comment: Thanks for the observation! Wodering if u have any idea to solve this problem? @egreg

Comment: Do you know this result is true? If so, could you please provide a reference?

Comment: Yes, its true. This is an exercise from Kasch`s Module and Ring theory, it is given in the chapter of Semiperfect and Perfect Rings its the exercise (5-2) at page 304. Thanks for checking out this problem. @Zeek

Comment: @Cos That book uses the term “indecomposable” in a rather nonstandard way, meaning “not the sum of two proper submodules”, and uses “directly indecomposable” for what is usually meant by indecomposable: not the *direct* sum of two proper submodules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may well be wrong, but I think only one direction of this is true.

If $M\cong M_{1}\oplus M_{2}$, then since $M_{1}$ and $M_{2}$ are quotients of $M$ they both have projective covers $\phi_{1}:P_{1}\to M_{1}$ and $\phi_{2}:P_{2}\to M_{2}$. Then $\phi_{1}\oplus\phi_{2}:P_{1}\oplus P_{2}\to M$ is also a projective cover by Proposition 5.5.4 of *Relative Homological Algebra* by Enochs and Jenda. Since projective covers are unique to isomorphism it follows that the projective cover of $M$ is not indecomposable. Hence that direction is true.

I believe I have a  counterexample to the other direction. Let $R$ be a local ring and $M$ a finitely generated $R$-module. Then a projective cover of $M$ is given by a map $R^{n}\to M$ where $n$ is the vector space dimension of the $R/\mathfrak{m}$-module $M/\mathfrak{m}M\cong (R/\mathfrak{m})^{n}$ (see Theorem 5.3.3 of RHA). In particular, if $M$ is an indecomposable module then $R^{n}$ will not be indecomposable if $n>1$. But there are local rings with indecomposable f.g. modules $M$ with $n>1$. For example over a complete hypersurface singularity you often find indecomposable maximal Cohen-Macaulay modules with $\mu(M)>1$.

Comment: Really nice proof and counterexample but as Rickard pointed, what this book meant by $M$ is descomposable is that there are not proper submodules $ \emptyset \neq M_{1}, M_{2}$ of $M$ such $M = M_{1}+ M_{2}$ and directly descomposable means that the same I wrote but with direct sum.  With this new definition I tried to emulate the first implication you have done but it fails as this way $M_{1}$ and $M_{2}$ cannot be thinked of quotients @Zeek